# DbContext vs Compiled Queries

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm currently working on a project that uses Entity framework for data persistence. It started  using Entity Framework 4 with EDMX and T4 template and ObjectContext with Objectset.A lot of Complied queries have been used for improving the query performance.

However, the approach is not extensible anymore because project team size has increased and Test Driven development need to be implemented. So we took the decision to convert using entity object in to POCO and DbContext for the support of Test Driven Development for repository integration test with data migration.

Unfortunately, we have realized that there is no support for complied queries for DbContext.
We decided to use two separate inherited context classes from DbContext for (CRUD) and ObjectContext (Complied Queries),  as in near future we can shift to auto compile query support with DbContext.

My Questions are

1. What are the consequences with can be occurred by implementing this approach ?
2. Is there any alternative approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered moving to .NET Framework 4.5? The core libraries in .NET Framework 4.5 compile and cache queries on the first use and you don't need to do anything special to take advantage of this functionality. See this blog entry for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/30/auto-compiled-linq-queries-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have seen the advantages.However, current implementation of Compiled Queries relatively big to refactor.